# Bar chart with new ios-charts framework new release

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

With the new release on ios-charts, some functions have changed, and now i am unable to put the Xvals (for example, each month) under each value. Anyone could help me?

How would u update this code with the new release?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"]
    let unitsSold = [20.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0, 16.0]

    setChart(months, values: unitsSold)

}

func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

    var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")
    let chartData = BarChartData(xVals: dataPoints, dataSet: chartDataSet)
    horChart.data = chartData
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the v3 release, you need to take a look at ChartsDemo how to use it. v3 has redesigned the x axis to support date-like axis, so some functions are changed.

Comment: Yes i am talking about v3 release, but i have already inspected charts demo and i still can't find a way to put the name under each bar like before.